# For Loops and While Loops with str and int conflictions

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop, int

I am trying to discover how to use for loops and where strings and ints can differentiate.

I created a function calling dimension and TV size: for example

```
def TVDisplay(dimension, TVsize):
    final = "<==="
    for i in range(TVsize-2):
        final = final + "=="
    final = final + "==>\n"

    for corner in dimension:
        final = final + "< "
        for edge in corner:
            final = final + edge + " "
        final = final + ">\n"

    final = final + "<==="
    for i in range(TVsize-2):
        final = final + "=="
    final = final + "==>\n"

    return final
```

This function returns

```
<=====>
< 0 0 >
< 0 0 >
<=====>
```

Based on a dimension that is [['0','0'],['0','0']] and a TVsize of 2.

Now I am trying to use while loops to make it look similar, but I am running into problems at the strings and int()s

My Function looks like this:

```
def TVDisplay(dimension, TVsize):
    final="<==="
    i=0
    while i < TVsize-2:
        final = final + "=="
        ctr+=1
    final = final + "==>\n"

    corner=0
    while corner < dimension:
        edge = 0
        final = final + "< "
        while edge < corner:
            final = final + edge + " "
            edge+=1
        final = final + ">\n"
        corner+=1

    final = final + "<==="
    while i < TVsize-2:
        final = final + "=="
        i+=1
    final = final + "==>\n"

    return final
```

This function returns this:

```
<=====>
<>
< 0 >
<=====>
```

I think it has to do with my middle part of code that is conflicting with strs or ints.

Does anyone have any advice how to fix this problem?

Thank you!!

EDITED::

```
corner=1
while corner < dimension:
    final = final + "< "
    edge = 0
    while edge < corner:
        final = final + edge + " "
        edge+=1
    final = final + ">\n"
   corner+=1
```

At the:

```
final = final + edge + " "
```

line, cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects appears.
my purpose to get the middle part of the loop is to spit out the middle part of the display

```
< 0 0 >
< 0 0 >
```

the last loop closes it off.

so thats my issue

Comment: What on earth is this supposed to be doing? What does `TVsize` mean? What does `dimension` represent? I would recommend sticking with `for` to avoid error-prone manual increments, but you should make that first version work properly first - try e.g. `TVDisplay([['0', '0'], ['0', '0']], 3)`.

Comment: Did you know that you can repeat strings with `*`? This means your first loop can be replaced by `final = "<=" + "=="*TVsize + ">\n"`. You can also join strings with `str.join`, so your inner loop can be replaced by `final += "< " + " ".join(corner) + " >\n"`.

Comment: corner=1
    while corner < dimension:
        final = final + "< "
        edge = 0
        while edge < corner:
            final = final + edge + " "
            edge+=1
        final = final + ">\n"
        corner+=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimension is a list of lists right?

So when you call:

```
for corner in dimension:
    for edge in corner:
```

It is referring to the actual object. So corner is a list and edge is an object in that list. 
It would be the same as saying:

```
while corner < len(dimension):
    edge = 0
    while edge < len(dimension[corner]):
         finale += dimension[corner][edge] + " "
```

The difference is that when you say:

```
for x in y
```

You are actually referring to the object x which is in y. However when you say:

```
while x < y:
    x+=1
```

X is only an integer (in your case it is the index of the object). To access the actual object you must use y[x]. The 'in' function refers to actual objects, whereas when you use a while loop you create a counter that keeps track of an index but not the actual object.

```
while corner_index < len(dimension):
    edge_index = 0
    corner = dimension[corner_index] #retrieve the list from dimension
    final = final + "< "
    while edge_index < len(corner):
        edge = corner[edge_index] #get the edge
        final += edge + " "
        edge_index+=1
    final = final + ">\n"
    corner_index+=1
```

To be even more succint:

```
while corner_index < len(dimension):
    edge_index = 0
    final = final + "< "
    while edge_index < len(dimension[corner_index]):
        final += dimension[corner_index][edge_index] + " "
        edge_index+=1
    final = final + ">\n"
    corner_index+=1
```

As to your edit:

The way you are accessing edge (as an index integer) means you must first typecast to a string. So:

final += str(edge) + " "

You didn't have this issue initially because 'edge' referred to the actual string object '0' in your dimensions list. However, when you use while loops, 'edge' is an integer that you are using as a counter.

Comment: I tried putting len(corner) but this spits out <<object of type 'int' has no len()>>

Comment: `corner` is an integer; what are you expecting `len(corner)` to do, exactly?

Comment: well, im trying to make the foor-loop middle part of the forloop do the same thing for while-loop